# Error [ERR_IPC_DISCONNECTED]: IPC channel is already disconnected

Tags: node.js, pm2

Has anyone faced this issue with a Docker image? I have an older version of Docker image running on the same server, which was built last week. But when I tried to run another version of Docker image that I've built today without changing anything that might cause this issue, I was facing the error.

I am clueless about what might have happened to my server or application.

- Application runtime: Node.js 14
- PM2 version: 5.3.1
- Docker version: 19.03.1

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_IPC_DISCONNECTED]: IPC channel is already disconnected
    at ChildProcess.target.disconnect (internal/child_process.js:865:26)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@pm2/agent/src/InteractorClient.js:238:13)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.target.disconnect (internal/child_process.js:865:12)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@pm2/agent/src/InteractorClient.js:238:13)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
  code: 'ERR_IPC_DISCONNECTED'
}
```

Comment: looks like it has  to do with the IPC (Inter-Process Communication) channel being disconnected. Check docker logs to see if anything acting funny.